# How to route vpn through proxy?

Tags: networking, server, proxy, vpn, tor

I have an ISP (public hospital) who is blocking everything through a program called Fortiguard. It's very annoying. Its blocking my public library as a terrorist organization, my work email saying its considered social media, my computer support and coding sites under the category of "Hacking".

However Crackle, Netflix, Youtube, Facebook, and Pandora seem to work well. I'm surprised these website are even working. VPN's don't work. Changing the DNS server doesn't work. HTTPS doesn't even keep me safe. The only thing which does work is Tor. I would like to route all my system connections through a trusted exit node in Tor.

I figured the best way to do this was to create a VPN server with a hidden service address (vps is limited in bandwidth) in on my VPS (if they haven't blocked `ssh`). To do this I need to route everything through the Tor proxy and then to the hidden service address via the vpn protocol. I'm staying here for three more days and I would really love to give this hospital IT a piece of my mind but to avoid confrontation I would much rather just cut the crap and bypass all this.

**Long story short:** Is there a way to route vpn through proxy? So the Internet access will work like this:

> PC --> Proxy --> VPN --> Internet

Answer (score 6):

[Read the official manual](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http).

You can launch openvpn in the next manner:

```
# openvpn --config config.file --http-proxy 127.0.0.1 3128
```

However, http-proxy doesn't support UDP, probably, you can do this only with TCP vpn.

But there is --socks-proxy option for openvpn, you can use socks5 instead of http-proxy, socks5 do both UDP and TCP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VPN, but its a solution to get around the proxy servers.
Install sshd if it isn't already.

```
sudo install sshd
```

Have sshd listen on a non-standard port. In in /etc/ssh/sshd_config you will see

```
port 22
```

You either change that port number or make sshd listen on multiple ports with several port directives like

```
port 22
port 5743
```

Change the port number or leave as you wish.

Load the new configuration with the command:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Install squid proxy server on your sshserver.

```
 sudo apt-get install squid3
```

Have the squid proxy server listing to say port 8080 on 127.0.0.1 of your sshd server by modifying the file /etc/squid3/squid.conf .

```
http_port 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And that you can connect to it with these lines

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
```

Load the new configuration with the command

```
 /etc/inid.d/squid3 restart
```

You can now use putty or any other ssh client on a machine at work to connect to your sshserver. An example for the command line:

```
ssh -L 8081:127.0.0.1:8080 user@sshserver -p 5743
```

Last step, set your browser's proxy settings to port 8081 of 127.0.0.1 . When your browser makes a request to the local machines address 127.0.0.1 port 8081, your ssh client listening to that port will tunnel the request to your sshserver listening on port 5743 of the sshserver. The ssh server will then forwards the traffic clear text to the squid proxy server listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080 of the sshserver. The proxy serve running on your sshserver will now proxy your web browser's request to youtube, facebook google ect.

Answer (score 0):

see [Connect to OpenVPN over Shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Connect-to-OpenVPN-over-Shadowsocks)